# How do I make these Flexbox columns work simply?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

When width >960px, this element looks great with a row of three columns, but when I go smaller than 960 the cards default to one column.

I am unsure how to style this so that it has a desired behavior of going form three columns, to two columns and then one column

What does the community suggest?

Note: this was lifted from https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/item-groups

code pen: https://codepen.io/gene-yllanes/pen/gJYqzq?editors=1010

```
<v-item-group>
  <v-container grid-list-md>
    <v-layout wrap>
      <v-flex
        v-for="n in 9"
        :key="n"
        xs12
        md4
      >
        <v-item>
          <v-card
            slot-scope="{ active, toggle }"
            :color="active ? 'primary' : ''"
            class="d-flex align-center"
            dark
            height="200"
            @click="toggle"
          >
            <v-scroll-y-transition>
              <div
                v-if="active"
                class="display-3 text-xs-center"
              >
                Active
              </div>
            </v-scroll-y-transition>
          </v-card>
        </v-item>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</v-item-group>
```

Comment: `xs12 sm6 md4` The `sm6` will help with that.

Comment: Oh you are awesome! Does this mean that when it is "sm" set the grid layout to 6 out of 12? AKA display 2 when small?

Comment: Simple. Elegant. Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: I toured through the documents and didn't understand this at all. How is something so simple not blaringly obvious?

Comment: Yeah, it's not exactly spelled out. the `xs / sm / md / lg / xl` represent corresponding breakpoints for media query widths that you can observe. You can also programatically change things with `this.$vuetify.breakpoint.(smAndDown / mdAndUp)`, and a whole plethora of other breakpoint options.

Comment: May you please submit and answer so I could accept this as the solution? Also, could you suggest a more accurate title?

Comment: Hey there, may you please make your comment into an answer?